# Do something when app is closed

Tags: android, exit, application-shutdown

I'm using `onDestroy()` to do something when my app is closed, but it doesn't work when I close my app from the menu (by tapping the soft key to the left of the home button on Samsung Galaxy for example). So I deduce that it doesn't call the `onDestroy()` method when I kill my app. How can I do something when I shut my application this way?

Comment: There is no requirement for `onDestroy()` to be called on all components in all situations. There is no requirement for *anything* to be called when your process is about to be terminated. Whatever you are trying to do should be done sooner, such as when the app's UI moves into the background.

Answer (score 1):

First create this service class:

```
 public class ExitService extends Service {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        System.out.println("onTaskRemoved called");
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        //do something you want before app closes.
        //stop service
        this.stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Then, declare this way your service in the manifest  label:

```
<service
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".ExitService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Now, just start the service wherever you want to do something before your app closing.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExitService.class);
        startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might consider moving your code to the onPause() area of the lifecycle. This is usually a preferred place to save stored data and prepare to close out whereas onDestory() is a better place to close open handles which might be closed anyway by the system during forced termination.

Answer (score 0):

`onDestroy()` is not necessarily always called. So you need to perform all task in `onStop()` or `onPause()` call back.

Comment: `onStop()` and `onPause()` are called when I change activity but I don't want to do it when i change activity, only when I close my app